# Concatenating every third list

Tags: list, haskell

I have a big list of lists. And I want to `concat` every third list into each other. Like such

```
let xss = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],
           [7,8,9],[7,8,9],[7,8,9]]

someFunk xss = [[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                [4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6],
                [7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9]]
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Sure there is. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yeah. `catThird (xs:xss) = xs ++ take 9 (catThird xss)` But it only works on the first 3 lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
someFunk :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
someFunk (x:y:z:zs) = (x ++ y ++ z) : someFunk zs
someFunk (x:y:ys) = (x ++ y) : someFunk ys
someFunk (x:xs) = x : someFunk xs
someFunk _ = []
```

Using pattern matching, you check for a list with at least three lists, join them and recursively call it on the remainder of the list. If the list count is not an exact multiple of 3, the subsequent patterns still allow you to concatenate the next 3 while available.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YKQW8567)

Comment: Nice. Didnt know you could pattern match like this `(x:y:z:zs)` but now when I see it, it makes sense!

Answer (score 11):

Just for bikeshedding purposes, I think I would write something like this:

```
import Data.List.Split
someFunk = map concat . chunksOf 3
```

It's concise, and I think it also reads a lot like your English description. It uses the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package.